# Autocomplete field from MySQL with PDO via JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

My fields used to work fine, however when I switched my configuration file which connects to my DB to use PDO, it stopped working. I updated the php file as below but still the data won't populate.

Below is my configuration file, and PHP file that pulls the data and sends it back to my page in JSON via AJAX. This is my first time working with PDO.

Configuration File:

```
class DatabaseService{

    private $db_host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "ca_us_data";
    private $db_user = "root";
    private $db_password = "";
    private $connection;

    public function getConnection(){

        $this->connection = null;

        try{
            $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->db_host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, 
            $this->db_user, $this->db_password);
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection failed: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->connection;
    }
}
?>
```

Fetcher File:

```
$databaseService = new DatabaseService();
$conn = $databaseService->getConnection();

if(!isset($_POST['selected_country'])){

    $keyword = strval($_POST['query']);
    $search_param = "%{$keyword}%";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT country_name FROM 'countries' WHERE country_name LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(':search_param', $search_param, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($num > 0){
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $countryResult[] = $row["country_name"];
        }
    echo json_encode($countryResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What do you see when you `print_r($conn->errorInfo());`?

Comment: I think there is no ':search_param' in your query replace ? with :search_param and try again

Comment: I am not getting any errors in the log file. I replaced the ? with :search_param but I get no results.

Comment: `'countries'` should be without quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no `':search_param'` in your query replace `?` with `:search_param` and try again:

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT country_name FROM countries WHERE country_name LIKE :search_param");
    $stmt->bindParam(':search_param', $search_param, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: This is my ajax request:

$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('#country').typeahead({
        
        source: function (query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "../includes/fetcher.php",
                data: 'query=' + query,            
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    result($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return item;
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });

Comment: is query = selected country ?, if yes then replace 'query=' with 'selected_country=', and also your datatype is json if you dont require it then remove dataType

Comment: query carries whatever is typed in the text box, for autocomplete purpose. selected_country, if it is not set, fetcher knows to go and look in the countries DB, once it is set, based on it I look for provinces of that country, and so on for the city.

Comment: I am not sure if that makes sense, but it works fine when I did not use PDO to connect to the DB.

Comment: maybe the problem is in  if(!isset($_POST['selected_country']))  thats why your code is not executing,try to inspect this

Comment: That is the point Aryan, if country is not set, I look for the country in DB. once the cursor moves to the province text box, js sets the country and passes it to fetcher to obtain the province. But I am not able to retrieve the country so I could set it. I have multiple if statements in the fetcher file to autocomplete the country, province, and city

Comment: ok! just a thought

Comment: try edited code I changed 'countries' to countries when I debugged it was showing me this error